# Select a new object including a where

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

How can we use the `Where` with **Linq** when we select a new object ?

Here is what I have :

```
From x In mydb.vw_TransactionsWithNames 
Select New datetransaction() With {.start = x.StartDate, .ends = x.EndDate} 
Where x.fkCommunity = c.PkCommunity And x.isCancelled = 0
```

But I have an error after the `Select New datetransaction() With {.start = x.StartDate, .ends = x.EndDate}` -> **Name 'x' is either not declared or not in the current scope**

Thank you.

Comment: USe the where clause first

Comment: You also need a variable to accept the expression: `Dim query = From...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the expression concrete by stating the type expected. The Where clause goes before the Select statement. The `query` is an `Anonymous Type` and is a collection of the results.

```
Dim query = From x As {datatype here} In mydb.vw_TransactionsWithNames 
            Where x.fkCommunity = c.PkCommunity And x.isCancelled = 0
            Select New With {.start = x.StartDate, .ends = x.EndDate}
```